# PostgreSQL Sqoop import + data line break issue

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

We are trying to import PostgreSQL data using apache sqoop in to Hadoop environment. On which, identified that direct(keyword: --direct) mode of SQOOP import using the PostgreSQL COPY operation to fast import the data in to HDFS. If the column is having a line breaker(\n) as a value then the QUOTE is added in the column value(example as below:1) which was considered as another record in HIVE table(LOAD DATA INPATH). Is there alternative is available to make this work?

```
E1: Sample data in HDFS (tried importing with: Default or --input-escaped-by '\' or --input-escaped-by '\n' doesn't help)
value1,"The some data 
has line break",value3
```

Hive table considered it as 2 records.(provided:--hive-delims-replacement '' seems HDFS level data has \n hive detects as new record)

```
value1          "the same data  NULL
has line break"  value3         NULL
```

It seems apache retired this project seems it no longer support bug fixes or any release.

Any of you faced the same problem or any one could help me on this?

Note: I am able to import using non-direct and select query mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting your data to a non-text format (e.g. Parquet, "-as-parquetfile" sqoop flag). That would fix the issue with new lines.

Comment: Hi facha, In direct mode of postgresql sqoop import it was using the CSV as a file format no other format are supported it seems.